# The PowerShell script is not producing the anticipated JSON output as intended

Tags: json, powershell-7.3

powershell script not working as expected

I am trying to achieve below format output with my PowerShell script.
Expected Output:

```
"TestParam": {
    "5903-95856-24869-e43": {
         "CallerName": "testparner",
         "ClientId": "123-45-789",
         "ClientSecret": {
             "KeyVaultSecretName": "ClientSecret"
          }
     }
}
```

Script I am using

```
$PartnerName="testparner"
$ClientID="123-45-789"
$DM=@{
    "5903-95856-24869-e43"=@{
        "CallerName"= $PartnerName
        "ClientId"= $ClientID
        "ClientSecret"= @{
            "KeyVaultSecretName"= "ClientSecret"
        }
    }
}
$jsonData = @{
    "TestParam"= $DM
}
$jsonString = $jsonData | ConvertTo-Json
$jsonString
```

Actual output I am getting using above script:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJjVY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code; it is expected to address the problem you're facing.

```
$PartnerName="testparner"
$ClientID="123-45-789"
$DM=@{
    "5903-95856-24869-e43"=@{
        "CallerName"= $PartnerName
        "ClientId"= $ClientID
        "ClientSecret"= @{
            "KeyVaultSecretName"= "ClientSecret"
        }
    }
}
$jsonData = @{
    "TestParam"= $DM
}
$jsonString = $jsonData | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4
$jsonString
```